# pictures does not apeare in posts

Tags: links, htaccess

I installed last version of wordpress by activating network.
I can upload images or any media and insert into posts, But when I publish that,
medias including images or any other media.
My htaccess file includes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

How can I see my pictures in my blog? Please help.

Comment: Aren't the images showing up on the front-end only, or even in the post editor?

Comment: please add more info, your question is very incomplete and it's hard to understand the problem. What url you getting in images? or they don't apear at all in image src tag? maybe you in media settings added URL of where files uploaded? it should be empty

Comment: I can see the pictures in editor, but when I want to see them in preview or publish, I cant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct `.htaccess` for a multi-site setup looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Note the rule for `files`: That’s how WordPress locates your images. You need also a `blogs.dir` directory in your `wp-content` directory.

Comment: Thanks. Seems my htaccess was written and changed by some plugins. Thanks again.